# VBA Use the Button Name which was clicked

Tags: vba, excel

In my workbook i have two worksheets ("Overview" & "Assignment_Data"). On the first sheet i have five ActiveX Buttons with different names ("WKA" / "WKS" / "GM" / "IBN" / "PM")

Each Button opens the UserForm "Add_Assignment", which has also two Buttons ("Save" & "Cancel"). The Data of the UF should be saved in the sheet "Assignment_Data".

Now i want if i click, for example, the Button WKA the data should be saved in Range A:C; for the Button WKS in Range E:G. Also the Button Name should be used as Headline in row 1.

Unfortunatly i have no idea how to do that.

**Buttons:**

```
Private Sub WKA_Click()
    Add_Assignment.Show
End Sub

Private Sub WKS_Click()
    Add_Assignment.Show
End Sub

Private Sub GM_Click()
    Add_Assignment.Show
End Sub

Private Sub IBN_Click()
    Add_Assignment.Show
End Sub

Private Sub PM_Click()
    Add_Assignment.Show
End Sub
```

**UserForm:**

```
Private Sub Save_Click()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim Col1 As Integer, Col2 As Integer, Col3 As Integer

    Set ws = Worksheets("Assignment_Data")
    If "ButtonName" = "WKA" Then
        Col1 = "A"
        Col2 = "B"
        Col3 = "C"
    ElseIf "ButtonName" = WKS Then
        Col1 = "E"
        Col2 = "F"
        Col3 = "G"
    ElseIf ' goes on till PM

    End If

    ws.Range(Col1 & "2").Value = Add_Assignment.Controls("TextBox1")
    ws.Range(Col2 & "2").Value = Add_Assignment.Controls("TextBox2")
    ws.Range(Col3 & "2").Value = Add_Assignment.Controls("TextBox3")
    ws.Range(Col1 & "3").Value = Add_Assignment.Controls("TextBox4")
    ws.Range(Col2 & "3").Value = Add_Assignment.Controls("TextBox5")
   ' and so on

    Add_Assignment.Hide
End Sub

Private Sub Cancel_Click()
    Add_Assignment.Hide
End Sub
```

**EDIT:**

**Code with Application.Caller:**

```
Private Sub Save_Click()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim Col1 As Integer, Col2 As Integer, Col3 As Integer
    Dim name As String

    name = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).name ' in this line i get the error

    Set ws = Worksheets("Assignment_Data")
    If name = "WKA" Then
        Col1 = "A"
        Col2 = "B"
        Col3 = "C"
    ' ...
    End If

    ' Do something

End Sub
```

Comment: Sounds like you might be able to use Application.Caller

Comment: @QHarr My thinking, exactly

Comment: I tried it with Application.Caller .. but i always get runtime error '13

Comment: Perhaps show that code and explain on which line the error occurs.

Comment: This is easier with Forms buttons as you can tie them all to the same sub in a normal module. Then you use Application.Caller to get the clicked button's name and pass that to a property you create in the Userform.

Comment: btw, `If "ButtonName" = "WKA"` will always return False, remove the quotes

Comment: @QHarr see my edit :) In the line with application.caller the error appears that the element with the name could not be found

Comment: You could add a label to your form, call if for instance **AssignmentLabel** then when you call your form replace the caption for the label. This example for **WKA**: `Add_Assignment.AssignmentLabel.Caption = "WKA"` just before `Add_Assignment.Show`. When your form has opened, you can do an if statement referencing the AssignmentLabel.Caption value.

Comment: @5202456 this works perfect .. thank you so much. this is such an easy solution. so good. thank you

Comment: Application.Caller doesn't seem to play nicely with ActiveX command buttons but there are these alternatives: https://www.ozgrid.com/forum/forum/help-forums/excel-general/130779-vba-return-name-of-activex-button-just-clicked. Form control may be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Is it necessary to use a Form? It sounds like this could be achieved with a simple `MsgBox`:

```
Sub confirmSave(btn_name As String)
    Dim res As VbMsgBoxResult
    res = MsgBox("Save?", buttons:=vbOKCancel)
    If res = VbOK Then ...
End Sub
```

and putting the values you want to copy in a separate sheet. So instead of doing

```
ws.Range(Col1 & "2").Value = Add_Assignment.Controls("TextBox1")
ws.Range(Col2 & "2").Value = Add_Assignment.Controls("TextBox2")
...
```

you just need to

```
ws.Range(StartCol & "2:" & EndCol & "3").Value = TemplateSheet.Range("A2:C3").Value ' or wherever the range is
```